# Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.2-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: r, installation, dependencies, ubuntu-18.04

while installing R on Ubuntu 18, I got this error

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.2-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: r-recommended (= 4.1.2-1.1804.0) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I have deleted R completely and its previous dependencies.

could you please give a favour? thanks